# File.createNewFile() is ignored when saving Camera photo

Tags: android

I am having an issue attempting to save a camera taken image into the phone's storage, but I keep getting an error I have not seen before saying that File.createNewFile() will be ignored. Does anyone how this can be corrected so that the photo can be saved? Or is there another, possibly better, way that I can save the image that has been captured by the camera and display it in the ImageView as well? The problem area can be found in onActivityResult() under PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA else if statement.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.stins.orbotcamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private EditText imageComment;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private TextView imageLat, imageLong;
    private String mLat, mLong;
    private File destination = null;
    private String imgPath = null;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.1.77/UploadExamples/upload.php";

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private final int PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA = 1, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY = 2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageComment);
        imageLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageLat);
        imageLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageLong);

        //fab.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            fab.setEnabled(false);
            imageComment.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectImage();

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fab.setEnabled(true);
                imageComment.setEnabled(true);
            }

            else{
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Accept all permissions to use app", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);


                snackbar.show();
        }


        }

    }

    public void selectImage(){

        try {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            int hasPerm = pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, getPackageName());
            if (hasPerm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose From Gallery","Cancel"};
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select Option");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA);
                        } else if (options[item].equals("Choose From Gallery")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY);
                        } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void uploadImage() {
        //getting name for the image
        String name = imageComment.getText().toString().trim();

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(file);


        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("latitude", mLat)
                    .addParameter("longitude", mLong)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

            Log.d("Upload", "uploadImage: " + path);

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String document_id = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        if (document_id != null) {
            document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String path = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return path;
    }










    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            file = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), file);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        if (requestCode == 0) {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                     mLat = Double.toString(latitude);
                     mLong = Double.toString(longitude);

                    imageLat.setText(mLat);
                    imageLong.setText(mLong);

                    // \n is for new line
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                     final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "Current location recorded", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_location_on_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


                    snackbar.show();
                } else {
                    // Can't get location.
                    // GPS or network is not enabled.
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.

                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Picture Cancelled", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_cancel_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                snackbar.show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Error Taking Picture", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                snackbar.show();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA && (data!=null)) {
            try {
                file = data.getData();
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);

                Log.e("Activity", "Pick from Camera::>>> ");

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                        getString(R.string.app_name), "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                imgPath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY && (data!=null)) {
            file = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), file);
                Log.e("Activity", "Pick from Gallery::>>> ");

                imgPath = getPath(file);
                destination = new File(imgPath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "OrbotCamera");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("OrbotCamera", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_send:
                if(imageView.getDrawable()==null){
                    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout,"Sorry, you'll need an image for that!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else {
                    uploadImage();
                }
                return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close Orbot Camera?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i;
        if(v.getId()==R.id.fab)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);

        }

    }
}
```

Logcat

```
07-26 10:56:30.757 23865-23865/com.example.stins.orbotcamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.stins.orbotcamera, PID: 23865
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:111)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:519)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
                                                                                   at com.example.stins.orbotcamera.MainActivity.getPath(MainActivity.java:215)
                                                                                   at com.example.stins.orbotcamera.MainActivity.uploadImage(MainActivity.java:188)
                                                                                   at com.example.stins.orbotcamera.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:427)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3383)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:679)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:959)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11157)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Are you using Marshmallow or any newer version? Have you tried runtime permission?

Comment: Yes I'm using Marshmallow, and I did do runtime permissions for the camera and WRITE/READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Do I possibly need something else as well?

Comment: please add your logcat

Comment: @UpendraShah updated post with Logcat

Comment: what is the content of  `private Uri file;` after `file = data.getData();` ? is this a file name?

Comment: @k3b This is a debug log message I attached to that variable.  `07-26 11:28:56.033 5268-5268/com.example.stins.orbotcamera D/pickimagecamera: onActivityResult: null
07-26 11:28:56.038 5268-5268/com.example.stins.orbotcamera W/System.err:     at com.example.stins.orbotcamera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:351)`

Comment: @k3b It comes out null and then produces a System error at the line with `.createNewFile()`

Comment: read the sdk docs of Intent.ACTION_PICK and MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"";
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
            File file1 = new File(cacheDir, dir.toString());
            file1.delete();
            file = new File(dir, "temp.jpeg");

            FileOutputStream fo;

            try
            {
                fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fo);
                fo.flush();
                fo.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```